# Converting to double is changing my number C# 14.80 - > 1480

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, double, decimal

I'm reading .txt file and spliting values into array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < articleItems.Length; i++)
{
    List<string> splitStrings = articleItems[i].Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
    splitStrings[0] = splitStrings[0].Substring(12);
}
```

After that I'm trying to make object from those values, and everything is fine, but strange thing are happening here...

Here is the image from debugger, there is **14.80** at the beginning and when I convert that string to decimal  it becomes **1480**...:

[image]

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I've tried it before and it didn't worked..

Comment: Use:
    Convert.ToDecimal(splitStrings[3], new CultureInfo("en-US"));

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Double.Parse(splitStrings[2].ToString())
```